# Bad summary on DuckDuckGo featured results

Tags: bug

So, I was trying to go to the site, and accidentally searched for "Superuser", and got this.

[image: Image showing SuperUser.com as the top sponsored result, but with text advertising other services]

It routes correctly to this site, but it looks like someone hijacked the search term by submitting with an incorrect cache of the site (or maybe it dates back to a hacking attempt?). Or maybe it's just cached on one of the spam answers? I figured someone would want to know, and possibly submit to DuckDuckGo a more accurate cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Likely the search engine just cached the first question on the front page during a spam wave. The section after the `sjsjsj` appear to be tags and [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) [mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac) and [ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) would probably correspond with [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1796219/gold-rupee-loan-customer-care-helpline-number-9903184542-8670157530-gold-rupee) (10K rep link) posted yesterday.

For comparison and the curious:

[image]

Looks like it pretty much matches your summary.